# Having trouble with input in command line application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, input

```
#include "ellison.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        int errorOutput = Execute(argc, argv);
        switch (errorOutput)
        {
            case 0:
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "An error occured: " << ParseError(errorOutput);
                return ERROR;
                break;
        }
    }

    cout << "+---------------+  \n";
    cout << "| ellison 0.1.1 |  \n";
    cout << "+---------------+  \n\n";

    int errorOutput = 0;
    string input;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << ">";
        input = "";
        cin >> input;

        if (input == "quit")
        {
            if (errorOutput != 0)
                return ERROR;
            else
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }

        errorOutput = Execute(input);
        switch (errorOutput)
        {
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
                cout << "An error occured: " << ParseError(errorOutput);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This code compiles and runs fine.  The strange part is, that if I type in a long string of letters with one or more spaces, I have two greater than signs, instead of one.  Is there some kind of an error that I made?
I will add that this doesn't work with short input strings, and that this was compiled with Visual-C++ 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

std::cin only reads until the first space. Then, it doesn't flush the read buffer.
So, because of your "while(true)", when it gets to the second std::cin, it reads the second part of your input without waiting for a new input.
You should try std::getline(stream& readingBuffer, std::string& destination) instead. It will read the whole line, like such:

```
getline(cin, input);
```

Just don't use cin and getline at the same time unless you use cin.ignore(1) after using cin, because cin leaves a '/n' in the stream. If you use getline right after on the same stream, it will stop at that '/n', not reading what you wanted to read.